# Why we use random state to simulate in tomography?

Tags: state-tomography

To simulate tomography, we often chose a random state from the Haar measure. But why? If you have any reference for the specific reason, please let me know.

Comment: what kind of "simulation" do you have in mind? Can you link to the sources you're reading this from? I would say it's pretty natural to assess the quality of a reconstruction technique such as tomography by analyzing how it performs on "typical" (i.e. uniformly random) states. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.150401; yes, it's natural, but I need some explanations and references to illustrate this.

Comment: to illlustrate what exactly?

Comment: use random state to do the numerical simulation